# Slurm Job Array with Dependent Jobs

Tags: slurm

I have a set of dependent Slurm jobs that are successfully submitting. The jobs are setup as:

```
a   b
 \ /
  c
  |
  d
  |
  e
```

I need to submit this set of jobs 1000s of times, each time parametrized slightly differently. If I was going to be submitting a large batch of jobs without dependencies, I would use a job array to be kind to other users and the scheduler. What is the best practice for submitting job arrays of dependent jobs?

Possible wrinkle: Each job (a/b - e) is parameterized slightly differently for SBATCH (nodes, tasks-per-node, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--dependency` option of `sbatch` accepts `aftercorr` to link each job in an array to the corresponding job (the job with the same task array ID) in another array.

The sequence would be (untested)

```
ArrayAID=$(sbatch --array=1-1000 A.sh)
ArrayBID=$(sbatch --array=1-1000 B.sh)
ArrayCID=$(sbatch --array=1-1000 --dependendy=aftercorr:$ArrayAID,$ArrayBID C.sh)
ArrayDID=$(sbatch --array=1-1000 --dependendy=aftercorr:$ArrayCID A.sh)
ArrayEID=$(sbatch --array=1-1000 --dependendy=aftercorr:$ArrayDID A.sh)
```

The *i*th job in array C will will wait for the *i*th job in each array A and B to complete before starting.

Slurm will most probably schedule jobs in array A before those in the other arrays but that depends on the characteristics of the job and the load of the cluster. You can use the `--nice` option to alter the ordering and guide it the way you want (either having all of array A finished as soon as possible or having entire workflows finished as soon as possible, in which case you would make job E higher priority than job D, itself higher priority than job C.)

Comment: Is there any way that this could be set up so that jobs would be started alternatively from two arrays, A and B, in the order  ```A[i], B[i], A[i+1], B[i+1], ...``` ?

Comment: Yes, with `--dependency=aftercorr...` if I recall correctly.

Comment: I can get ```B[i]``` to run after ```A[i]``` by using ```aftercorr```, but ```A[i+1]``` will start after ```A[i]``` not after ```B[i]```, i.e. ```B``` is dependent on ```A```, but not the other way round.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, in that case I would consider this is a single job array whose behaviour depends on the fact that `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` is odd or even, and that I would restrict to one job at a time with `--array=....%1`

Comment: But a single job array would request the same resources for each job, whereas I want to be able to alternate between sets of resources.  In particular, only every second step requires a GPU. Currently it does not seem possible to make the second array aware of the first one.